# c# finding file in directories

Tags: c#, file, directory

I tried the following:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\plugins\*\", "plugin.json");
```

But couldn't get it to work, how would I do the following?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? find all files that ends with `plugin.json` or search for `plugin.json` in all sub directories ?

Comment: search for plugin.json in all sub directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search files matching *plugin.json* pattern in all sub-directories of *c:\plugins*:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\plugins\", "plugin.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```